# How to add custom HTML to column header without adding headerCellTemplate in angular-ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I would like to add small HTML to the Header Label e.g. `<br>`.

**With Column Definition**

In column definition I can add

```
headerCellTemplate: 
              '<div class="my-class">My very big <br>column name<br>really huh</div>'
```

**Without Column Definition**

This is essentially the question.

**Why I need this functionality?**

My own `headerCellTemplate` might work for adding simple `<br>` however in order for all the other things like sorting etc will not work and behave like other columns.

For that to work I will have to copy/paste the entire `ng-grid/headerCellTemplate` and add my `<br>`s. This is ugly hence those of you who have run into this situation please post your alternatives. (P.S. I am migrating from ng-grid to ui-grid)